# Run Flyway Java-based callbacks with Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, flyway

Is there a way to run [Flyway Java-based callbacks](https://flywaydb.org/documentation/api/hooks#callsbacks) with Spring boot?
I'm converting an existing project that after each migration updates some view definitions, and this is done by Java as it needs some extra logic. I know it could be done in pl/pgsql (we are using Postgres) but it is already done and tested in Java.

[Spring boot docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-database-initialization.html) says it is possible, but it is listed that the callback scripts should live in same dir as migrations, maybe this works just for SQL based callbacks.

This code works without Spring Boot:

```
    Flyway flyway = new Flyway();
    flyway.setDataSource(this.getDataSource());
    flyway.setLocations("/db/migration");
    flyway.setCallbacks(new LogMaintenanceFlywayCallback());
    flyway.migrate();
```

I have several migrations in `/db/migration` and after each one I need to execute my callback. It works in my current project and I need to do the same (or another way to get the same behavior) in Spring Boot.

Comment: It works. You need to put your Java classes in the `db.migrations` package.

Comment: Do they have to be named in a standard? I had created a `SomeMaintenanceFlywayCallback`, implementing interface `FlywayCallback` and method `afterEachMigrate` does not get called. I have tried to rename the class to `AfterEachMigrate`, but no success too. It is in `db.migrations` package, side by side with a Java migration that is executed, so the build path is ok.

Comment: SQL migrations should be in `src/main/resources/db/migration`. Java migrations should be in `src/main/java/db/migration`. Each file normally starts with `Vxxx__some-text-here.sql` or  Vxxx__MyJavaClass.java`.

Comment: Just saw my first comment was wrong. It is NOT `db.migrations`, but `db.migration`. See http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-database-initialization.html#howto-execute-flyway-database-migrations-on-startup

Comment: I wrote it wrong too, it is already in `db.migration`. As I said, my migrations are being executed, what I need is the callback, after each migration run some code. I have updated my question to include the manual way to use Flyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can have a configuration like this and it will work:

```
@Configuration
public class FlywayFactory {

    @Bean
    public FlywayMigrationInitializer flywayInitializer(Flyway flyway, FlywayCallback flywayCallback) {
        flyway.setCallbacks(flywayCallback);
        return new FlywayMigrationInitializer(flyway);
    }

    @Bean
    public FlywayCallback flywayCallback() {
        return new LogMaintenanceFlywayCallback();
    }
}
```

Comment: In theory the solution is correct, but following answers are more perfect for real problem solving. I went through the approach of FlywayMigrationStrategy

Comment: You shouldn't call the bean method directly. Either inject the callback, or make the callback class not a bean.

Answer (score 3):

There seems to be no possibility to set the callbacks in the Spring Boot autoconfiguration (See [FlywayAutoConfiguration.java](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/flyway/FlywayAutoConfiguration.java))

There are 2 things you can do:

1. Create your own `Flyway` instance in one of your `Configuration` classes. Spring Boot will not create his instance in case you do that.
2. Autowire the `Flyway` instance in one of your `Configuration` classes and call the `setCallbacks` method in a `PostConstruct` method (But it might be tricky to make sure you call the setter before the migration starts)

Answer (score 3):

Since method `setCallbacks(Callback... callbacks)` of the `Flyway` has been deprecated and will be removed in Flyway 6.0, you can use new API and `FlywayConfigurationCustomizer` to set up custom Java-based callbacks. Then the configuration is as below:

```
@Configuration
public class FlywayFactory {

    @Bean
    public FlywayConfigurationCustomizer flywayConfigurationCustomizer() {
        return configuration -> configuration.callbacks(new LogMaintenanceFlywayCallback());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can override the Flyway migration stragtey

```
@Component
public class CallbackFlywayMigrationStrategy implements FlywayMigrationStrategy {

    @Override
    public void migrate(Flyway flyway) {
        flyway.setCallbacks(new LogMaintenanceFlywayCallback());
        flyway.migrate();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define a bean of type `org.flywaydb.core.api.callback.Callback` as follows:

```java
@Bean
public Callback logMaintenanceFlywayCallback() {
    return new LogMaintenanceFlywayCallback();
}
```