# Flyway Java Migration Callback with autowiring service

Tags: java, spring, database-migration, flyway

I have a class

```
public class AfterMigrationCallback implements Callback
```

in which, after flyway migration I want to make a call to populate the database with data pulled in by a service, so I need to autowire the service in this callback.

I get a null pointer for the service when I try to autowire it:
`Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null at db.testdata.AfterMigrationCallback.handle(AfterMigrationCallback.java:38)`, so how do I get spring to inject the bean otherwise?

Comment: This answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/38083435/2071828

Comment: No, I am using the implementation that is mentioned in a comment there, the flywayConfigurationCustomizer bean, but autowiring within the callback does not work

Comment: Is the callback a bean?

Comment: no, its not a bean - that may be the issue but I'm not sure how to declare it as one and still keep the callback implementation

Comment: That’s what the linked answer demonstrates.

Comment: Thanks for the help - I actually ended up solving the issue by implementing a SpringUtility class that implements ApplicationContextAware in order to get a bean from the application context in the java migration - it was not listed in the answer.